# Docker pull: still having old image after pull

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I noticed that the docker image I'm using is older than the one on dockerhub. Running `docker pull` seems to work, but later when running `docker images` I still see the old image, even if I first explicitly removed it with `docker rmi`.

Output of docker pull:

```
# docker pull staltz/ssb-room
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from staltz/ssb-room
9a0b0ce99936: Already exists 
db3b6004c61a: Already exists 
f8f075920295: Already exists 
6ef14aff1139: Already exists 
0bbd8b48260f: Pull complete 
524be717efb1: Pull complete 
aad1e8812bc2: Pull complete 
13fb072986db: Pull complete 
627a2df19018: Pull complete 
fb8dcb3732a4: Pull complete 
2bc41d47dd50: Pull complete 
058f4db9be8e: Pull complete 
8f21c57f425d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:a7c49c796823312f8c1d155eb636bbd974bc55036c2180f16f17d3340fcebbe7
Status: Downloaded newer image for staltz/ssb-room:latest
docker.io/staltz/ssb-room:latest
```

Output of docker images:

```
# docker images staltz/ssb-room
REPOSITORY        TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
staltz/ssb-room   latest    6097b401900c   4 months ago   930MB
```

Why is it again showing that 4-months old image?